# Get tag's attribute if tag exists; otherwise None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a `td` tag in BeautifulSoup 4. There may be an `a` tag inside it:

```
row.find_all('td')[2].find('a')
```

If there is, I want to retrieve the `a` tag's `href` attribute. Otherwise, I'd like `None`.

This is what I've thought of:

```
getattr(row.find_all('td')[2].find('a'), 'attrs', {}).get('href')
```

What's an efficient way to do this?

Example row:

```
<tr><td><a href="http://google.com">405</a></td>
\n<td><font face="Arial" size="-1">12-Jul</font></td>\n<td><font face="Arial" size="-1">There could be an a-tag here.</fo
nt></td>\n<td><font face="Arial" size="-1">On Motion</font></td>\n<td align="CENTER"><fo
nt face="Arial" size="-1">F</font></td>\n<td><font face="Arial" size="-1">\xa0</font></td></tr>
```

Comment: What's the HTML you're parsing, at least of `row` and below.

Comment: @TankorSmash added

Answer (score 1):

You can select the second  tr and any anchor inside then check using an if:

```
a = soup.select_one("tr:nth-of-type(2) a[href]")


if a:
    print(a["href"])
```

If there is no anchor a will be None, if there is you can just extract the href.